# How I can select a file with R, in this script

Tags: r, file, select

Hi this is my script and I want only files with name 'pancreas'.
How can I add this in my script? I have txt files.

This is my script:

1. Generate list of files in folder:

   ```r
   files <- data.frame(list.files(folder, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = '\\.txt$')[1:200])
   colnames(files)[1] <- "path"
   ```
2. Drop records containing "slide.txt" in file name:

   ```r
   files <- subset(files, !grepl("slide.txt", files$path, fixed = TRUE))
   ```

Here's the screen shot of my code:

[image: screenshot of code]

Comment: Please *do not post screenshots of code*. Post the actual code itself.

Answer (score 1):

```r
files <- list.files(".", pattern = "\\.txt$", recursive = TRUE)
files
#> [1] "foo.txt"       "pancreas1.txt" "pancreas2.txt" "slide.txt"
pancreas_files <- grep(pattern = "pancreas", x = files, value = TRUE)
pancreas_files
#> [1] "pancreas1.txt" "pancreas2.txt"
```